# Make dijit TabContainer tabs same size and evenly stretch them to the size of the tab container

Tags: javascript, dojo, tabcontainer

Can you please tell me how to make the tabs same size and evenly stretch them to  the size of the `TabContainer`? Picture below shows the size of the tabs are different and they are left aligned. But i want to them to be same size which should be 1/3 of the tab container.

[image]

```
var tc = new TabContainer({
    style: "height: 100px; width: 100%;"
});

var cpOrg = new ContentPane({
     title: "Mississippi",
     content: "Mississippi"
});
tc.addChild(cpOrg);

var cpShared = new ContentPane({
     title: "Utah",
     content: "Utah"
});
tc.addChild(cpShared);

var cpPrivate = new ContentPane({
     title: "New York",
     content: "New York"
});
tc.addChild(cpPrivate);

tc.startup();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Simple just locate the class and apply style to it.

To do it dynamicly whatever number of tabs you have :

1. Calculate The number of childs
2. Calculate the width of the tabContainer
3. Apply to all child the calculated whidth ( whidth container / number of childs - other stuff)
4. Create `window resize` change event to make the `width` dynamic

Here is a solution :

```js
require([
 "dojo/query",
  "dojo/on",
 "dojo/dom-style",
  "dijit/layout/TabContainer", 
  "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(query,On,domStyle,TabContainer,ContentPane) {
  
  var tc = new TabContainer({
    style: "height: 100px; width: 100%;"
  },"tabContainer");

  var cpOrg = new ContentPane({
       title: "Mississippi",
       content: "Mississippi"
  });
  
  tc.addChild(cpOrg);
 
  var cpShared = new ContentPane({
       title: "Utah",
       content: "Utah"
  });
  tc.addChild(cpShared);

  var cpPrivate = new ContentPane({
       title: "New York",
       content: "New York"
  });
  
  tc.addChild(cpPrivate);
  tc.startup();
 
  changeTabWidth();
  
  function changeTabWidth(){
    // get the number of child of tabContainer
    var number_of_child = tc.containerNode.childElementCount;
    
    // calculate width of tabContainer and divide by number of child then 
    // every tab has 6px left and right padding + 1px border right so 
    // size must be 6+6+3-1 for the last tab = "14" that's why we remove 14 above from the width sum
    var width = (domStyle.get(tc.containerNode,"width")/number_of_child) - 14;
    
    query(".dijitTabInner.dijitTabContent.dijitTab").forEach(function(element){
      domStyle.set(element, {
        width: width+"px"
      });
    });
  }
  
  // event to change width after window size changed 
  On(window,"resize",function(){
   changeTabWidth();
  })
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="claro">
  <div id="tabContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle If you want :[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omdqdcwb/)